# I can't unrepresent LUN (SAN) devices from server

Tags: linux, storage, multipath

I've 22Tb lun from SAN Storage (HITACHI) on my Linux Server(CentOS 6.7).
I configure multipath for this lun, and now I wanna remove it.
The storage team deattach the lun from my server and when I run "multipath -ll"it still exists.

mpathf (360060e801667af00000167af0000014b) dm-2 HITACHI,OPEN-V*12
size=22T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled

|- 3:0:0:3 sdf 8:80  failed faulty running

`- 3:0:1:3 sdn 8:208 failed faulty running

this message stay until I reboot the server and i can't reboot all of my servers because they are in production environment.
anybody know what should I do?
Thanks

Comment: I rescan again after removing the lun by "echo "- - -" >/sys/class/scsi_host/hostn/scan
" command, but it doesnt work

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: ok, will move the question to those pages.
should I remove this question?thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to be sure the `mpathf` device is not being used:

```
lsof | grep mpathf
dmsetup info mpathf | grep -i open
```

In the `dmsetup info` open count needs to be equal to 0

So you are using the luns with lvm or something else, you need to remove everything from the lun.

Now you can delete sub disks with `echo 1 > /sys/block/<x>/device/delete`

Comment: I used this command to delete all of unusable path and it worked.
echo 1 >/sys/class/scsi_device/3:0:0:3/device/delete

Comment: @BEHXAD is the same command and has the same effect, you need to check if your mpathf is being used

Comment: yes, I used the same command and it worked.it just to inform you the command worked.